# Find ID of next instance of a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to find the ID (test1, test2, test3 etc..) of the next instance of a specific class (findMe).

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr id="test1" class="findMe">
      <td>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test2" class="findMe">
      <td>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <div id="test3" class="findMe">
    </div>
  </container>
```

JS:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
console.log($(this).parent().closest(".findMe").next().attr('id'));
})
```

I can find the ID "test2" but not "test3". Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `.findMe`'s nearest ancestor with the third `.findMe` is a *grandparent*, not a parent. (The `<tr>` is inside a `<tbody>`.)

While you could fix it (kinda) by making your dynamic DOM navigation more flexible, an easier method I think would be to select all `.findMe`s, then access the next index.

```
const findMes = $('.findMe');
const thisIndex = findMes.index(this);
console.log(findMes[thisIndex + 1]?.id);
```

You could also use `getElementsByClassName`, whose collection is live, instead of re-selecting all elements each time.